# Can I get feedback after releasing a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I released [my gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_buzz). According to RubyGems.org, I had over 200 downloads in under a week. I realise that a great deal of these will be indexing sites, library archives etc. It's unlikely that 200 people have downloaded and tried my single-device HID library already. It's a little tricky as it is for a specific device, which narrows the field of potential users a lot.

Is it possible to find out if any real users have tried it? Is there any way to request for feedback on the library and it's documentation?

Comment: I think you can get over 400 automated downloads from RubyGems for a never-used gem, per version (based on my observations of a gem that I fully expect no-one to be using). Might be a good question on http://opensource.stackexchange.com/ if asked about starter/small open source projects in general. Not sure if there is a ruby-specific answer beyond what I do = check dependencies

Comment: It's probably not all that ruby-specific, in all honesty. Although there may be a feature of rubygems.org that I've not discovered to help with this.

Comment: There are a few things e.g. http://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/json/reverse_dependencies.json which shows no-one else has published a gem that depends on yours - but tracking published dependencies in other gems isn't quite the same as what you are asking.

Comment: That is a nice feature, and will be a good indicator if it's really being used, in another gem. Not necessarily if it's being used at all, tho.